# Conditional .htaccess request_uri redirect (mod-rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On my Apache server, I'm moving an old domain to a new place, and it's going to share the same Apache setup as the previous one.

Say I have two domains:

- example.com (old domain)
- example.net (new domain).

If the request uri is the old domain then it should redirect to the new domain with its path such as `example.com/blog/great-post/` is 301 redirected to `example.net/blog/great-post/`

However if the request uri is `example.net/blog/great-post/` then it should not redirect to itself because it's already at its destination (and won't get stuck in a redirect loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup conditional rewrites using [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), please read the manual for more info.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Oops, had a typo. Should have been example.net on both lines. Just tested the fixed version and it's working for me locally. If it still doesn't work, double check that mod_rewrite is enabled on your server.